# Isn't the network layer hop-to-hop (as opposed to end-to-end)?

Tags: network-programming, router

[image]

> Using logical connections makes it easier for us to think about the
> duty of each layer. As the figure shows, the duty of the application,
> transport, and network layers is end-to-end. However, the duty of the
> data-link and physical layers is hop-to-hop, in which a hop is a host
> or router.

Data Communications, 5th edition, Behrouz A. Forouzan, p. 37

I can clearly and simply understand from the figure and agree that the application and the transport layers are end-to-end (as there are no intermediary devices between the sender (one end) and the receiver (the other end)).

I can also clearly and simply understand from the figure and agree that the data link and the physical layers are hop-to-hop (as opposed to end-to-end), as there are intermediary devices between the two ends and *hops* must be made to those intermediary devices before reaching the other end.

However, I cannot understand nor agree that the network layer is end-to-end too (as the author would like me to believe)! In the network layer, there is a router (an intermediary device) between the two ends, and a hop must be made to that router before the other end is reached. So, is the network layer not unambigously hop-to-hop?

---

[An alternate figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efv7C.png)

Comment: I agree. He is wrong. Nothing is end to end below the transport layer.

Comment: @user207421 I think I understand where he is coming from a bit. In the figure, there is only one application layer, one transport layer, and also **one** network layer, but there are two data link and two physical layers. As the network layer is not segmented (like the data link and physical layers), he chose to call it end-to-end, but there is still a router in between the two ends, so it still does not make a whole lot of sense to call the network layer end-to-end.